# Application state save/restore

Tags: ios, app-store, appstore-approval, application-state, state-restoration

I want to know if application state save/restore is mandatory or optional in order to get application approved for App Store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not mandatory, although they might possibly complain that you app doesn't provide sufficient user experience to be published on AppStore. But don't worry, this is very unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not. You can see the AppStore guidelines, as long as your app fall with these guidelines you should be ok.